# How do you divide two cells in Excel that have numbers and text in them?

Tags: excel, cell, percentage

I have two cells that both have text and numbers in them from a 'COUNTIFS' formula. Such as:

**Number of X: 4**

**Total Number of X: 10**

How do I divide the two outputted numbers together two calculate a percentage?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use string manipulation here. Assuming your supplied values are in `A1` and `B1`, respectively, you can use:

```
 =RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND(":", A1)-1)/RIGHT(B1, LEN(B1)-FIND(":", B1)-1)
```

Which isn't pretty, but neither is your data.

This will output `0.4` which you can format into a percentage or multiple by 100 or whatever suits your downstream needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use Custom Formats:

[image]

Then only the number is stored and you can do simple math:

```
=C3/C2
```

[image]